# How can I boot my iMac directly into my old user name?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, boot, login

My MacBook Pro (MBP) upgrade to OS X El Capitan went awry. It hung at about 60% and accepted my password but still just sat there. So I decided to empty an external drive and put Yosemite on it, boot from the external on the MBP, and rescue as many files as possible from the MBP. This did not work.

When I went back to my iMac (from which I installed Yosemite) the HDD also installed a fresh copy of Yosemite on the iMac. When I looked under users, I can click on my old user name and all my files are there (Thank God!)

My question is: how can I boot my iMac directly into my old user name and use my files?

Comment: So you can see your old user name by looking at the files. What is holding you back from trying to log in with your old user name, or simply moving the files?

Comment: Yep, that would be the right thing to do if I had that option! I can only log into the new version (Which btw is using my iCloud password) Any other suggestions or perhaps this is another way of getting back to my original account. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can remember it should be enough to create a new user and select as short name the exact same value as your user folder is called. If you try to log into this new Account you should be able to access all files.

I found this workaround when trying to change my user name.
More here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201548 under the section "Change an account name"